# Scikit Learn: KMeans Clustering 3D data over a time period (dimentionality reduction?)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, dimensionality-reduction

I have a **dataset of xyz coordinates with a date component** in a pandas dataframe

ex:

- date1: $[x_1,y_1,z_1]$,
- date2: $[x_2,y_2,z_2]$,
- date3: $[x_3,y_3,z_3]$,
  ..

I would like to **classify a sample of object positions over the period of a week**
(using indexes to re-map the classification label back to the date), like this:

- Week 1: $[x_1,y_1,z_1], [x_2, y_2, z_2], [x_3,y_3,z_3], [x_4,y_4,z_4], [x_5,y_5,z_5], [x_6,y_6,z_6], [x_7,y_7,z_7]$,
- Week 2: $[x_8,y_8,z_8],[x_9,y_9,z_9],[x_{10},y_{10},z_{10}],[x_{11},y_{11},z_{11}],[x_{12},y_{12},z_{12}],[x_{13},y_{13},z_{13}],[x_{14},y_{14},z_{14}]$,

When I try to run KMeans it returns

```
k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=cclasses)
k_means.fit(process_set.hpc)
date_classes = k_means.labels_

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Expected <= 2
```

Questions:

- Do I have to run it through Principal Component Analysis (PCA) first? if so, how do I maintain date mapping to the classification created?
- Are there any other methods I could use?
- Am I doing everything completely backwards and should consider a different approach, any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you consider your data set time series?

Comment: If you want to classify data, you should not use a clustering method.

Comment: Please include a printout of `process_set` and `process_set.hpc` (the first few lines as printed by `pandas` are enough).  Also, please clarify if you want to **cluster** or **classify** this dataset.  You cannot classify if you do not have pre-existing labels.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to ask questions in comment for clarification before answering it, so I'm going to do both here.

#### Here are the things that would help answering this question for now:

Can you post part of the `process_set.hpc`?

What's its format? Is it a numpy array? Is it a Pandas dataframe?

What's the value of `cclasses`?

#### And now the answer:

First of all, `k-means` algorithm is able to find clusters in any n-dimensional data. If `n` is too big, it is better to use PCA but for `n=3` that wouldn't necessarily add any value.

The second thing that looks suspicious to me is that in the documentation for `kmeans` in `scikit-learn`, there is no `compute_labels` option, as seen [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). However, that option exists for `MiniBatchKMeans` as seen [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html).

Also, if you make your data in the form of a pandas dataframe (if it is not already so), things would be much easier to track and you won't have to reattach the timing information to your data afterwards.

I may be able to give you a more thorough answer if I know a bit more about the format of the data.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide more details about the processing you're doing to the data, I think the responses would be a little more helpful.

Here are a few things to consider:

- What's the shape of your data going into k-means? Are you aggregating up to the week level? If so, then your data won't look like the example you posted, since that seems like daily data.
- Try using .[shape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape) on your output data set. Does the # of rows match the data set you put into it? (This ties in to question #1. You'll be unable to join back directly if your original data is daily and the k-means data is weekly.
- I'm not sure if this is what you're attempting, but just declaring `data_classes` as the labels isn't going to add them back in to your original data. Like oxtay suggested, using pandas is a good choice because it will allow you to [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).